# Sudo pip uninstall

Tags: pip, sudo

I recently downloaded pip using sudo pip install. I then tried to download a package but was not able to install it. How can I uninstall sudo pip and make sure it's out of my system - to avoid risks of sudo pip?

Comment: There is no program called `sudo pip`, so it doesn’t make sense to uninstall it. And what do you mean by “risks of `sudo pip`”? Also, what system are you on?

Comment: I installed pip under sudo. I was reading that if you run it under sudo, you run arbitrary Python code from the Internet as root which might be dangerous. I'm currently using macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Please checked packages you installed.

```
$ pip list
...
package0
package1
package2
...
```

Then, you uninstall some packages you choose.

```
$ sudo pip uninstall package1
$ pip list
...
package0
package2
...
```

Comment: I was able to uninstall it. However when i'm trying to reinstall pip i'm getting the following error: No such file or directory

Comment: I maybe understood that (1) you used ```pip``` which is pre-installed on mac and (2) you did ```sudo pip uninstall pip``` , didn't you? If it is correct, you uninstalled pip which is pre-installed on mac. ```pip``` was removed from your system, so your system returned ```No such file or directory``` when you tried to use ```pip```. I think that ```sudo easy_install pip``` is the way how to re-install pip to your system.